# How to get Flutter SDK path after installing using Homebrew

Tags: flutter, sdk, homebrew

**Installed flutter using homebrew:**
https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/flutter#default

*I can't find the SDK Path, tried copy and pasting this:*

1./opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.0.5/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh,
and, /opt/homebrew/bin/flutter'

but the result shows that the folder specified as the FLUTTER SDK home does not exist, how am I able to find the Flutter SDK path

Answer (score 32):

Type `flutter doctor -v` in Terminal, the first line will show the location!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at it the whole time and couldn't figure it out! Can I do the following to add the path permanently https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xfRTp6tN5E&ab_channel=FlutterMapp [Minute 1:22-3:01].

Comment: “add flutter to path mac permanently” Code Answer
Open Terminal.
nano ~/.zshrc.
Add: export PATH=[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin:$PATH.
Run: source ~/.zshrc.
restart terminal.
Run: flutter doctor -v.

Comment: In my case I have `Flutter version 3.0.1 at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.10.4/flutter` anyone knows why we have 3.0.1 and 2.10.4 ?

Comment: @AAkrm you have updated the 2.10.4 to 3.0.1 via `flutter upgrade` and not with `brew upgrade flutter`. That is the reason for the difference.

Answer (score 1):

1. find your homebrew futter path

   ```
   flutter doctor -v
   ```
2. Copy the path under the Flutter stable channel info, eg. • Flutter version 3.0.5 at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.0.5/flutter
3. Open vsCode settings, search flutter path, add the path you just copied to these two places:

- Dart: Flutter Sdk Path (inside the JSON file)
- Dart: Flutter Sdk Paths

4. Reload vsCode

Answer (score 0):

If you install `flutter` using `brew install --cask flutter` and you are on macOS version `12.2.1`. Then `flutter` is located in the `Caskroom` folder.

For example, `usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.10.3/flutter`

In my case I installed flutter version `2.10.3` so that is the reason you use flutter SDK located inside the version `folder/directory`.